# Vim - go to next match + change word + paste clipboard does not work

Tags: vim, neovim

In my Vim, hitting `cw` (change word) and then `command + v` (MacOS paste shortcut) is able to replace the word on cursor to the clipboard copied one, but if I search some word then press `n` to go to the next match, and then do the same thing with `cw` then `command + v`, the copied one are not able to be pasted (it dose not show up) until I press `ESC`. It used to work normally.

What could be the possible cause of this?

Comment: If you have to press `ESC` does that mean you are in a different mode than normal when you search?

Comment: @wxz No, it was in normal mode. The time line is like,  search (normal mode) > `n` to jump to next match (normal mode) > `cw` to change word (insert mode) > `command + v` (insert mode) > `Esc` (normal mode)

Comment: Are you able to paste the word outside of vim? As in, is there a chance by searching in vim, you're clearing the clipboard copied word?

Comment: @wxz yes, I'm able to paste outside, the clipboard is not cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by romainl/vim-cool, it used work without this issue, maybe because I changed vim config or installed some other new plugins that don't fit with it.

Comment: @Romainl is a user on here. Might have ideas on how to help. Not sure if I can tag him though.